# Problems with alignment of listview item

Tags: android, listview, alignment

I have a problem with the alignment of the various fields in each row of a listview .
does anyone know how to go b under b , c under c , etc. ..

Thanks !!

since I can not post the screenshot , I try to make an image

AAAAAAA       BBBBBB    CCCCCC    DDDDDD     (this is my title)
aaa   bbb   ccc   ddd                        (this is my listview item)

how can i align it?

Comment: Post code and share screenshot on http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/upload/ and give a link here

Comment: Your requirement sounds like a grid view, not a list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you the use of Tables for things like this.
You can define a layout which will be set for **every** row in your ListView.
This row will have 4 parts with the same width and the should be equals to each other in the same row and in different rows along the list view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AAAAAAA"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BBBBBBBB"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CCCCCCCC"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DDDDDDDD"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

You can set your style there and whatever you want...

I hope this would help!!